# Using VB.net hw to find a substring and copy the entire line

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

þTEST000001þþTEST000001þþTEST000001þþTEST000001þþ0þþCanning, Simonþþþþ1/8/2014þ
þTEST000002þþTEST000002þþTEST000003þþTEST000002þþ0þþSolemon, Simonþþþþ2/4/2013þ

My string has the above content where i would like to find the text "TEST000002" which is only within the first delimiter (i.e. þ þ) and once i found the text i would like to copy the entire line into a text file...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split` + `Contains` and `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` to take the first matching line:

```
string firstMatchingLine = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Split('þ').Contains("TEST000002"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

or this approach using `Enumerable.Any` + `String.Trim` to remove leading or trailing spaces first:

```
string firstMatchingLine = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Split('þ').Any(t => t.Trim() == "TEST000002"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

To append it to a text file you can use:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("Path", new[] { firstMatchingLine });
```